# How long does it take to create a large table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I imported a table with 30 million rows from a text file to a MYSQL table it only took 1 minute. However, I realized that I missed a column and that I needed to add it to the table. From the MYSQL command line, I wrote the following command:

```
create tableC as(tableA.T1, tableB.ZID from tableA, table B where A.ZID = B.ZID)
```

It's been over one hour and the command has not terminated. Does anyone know the reason why? TableB was already in the MYSQL server.

Comment: did you check whether the datas actually were into the table after the 1st import?

Comment: and are you sure of `where A.ZID = B = ZID` ??

Comment: Yes the data actually exists and I am sure about the A.ZID = B.ZID

Comment: look at your code: it is not `A.ZID = B.ZID` but `A.ZID = B = ZID`

Comment: That was a typo. The process has still not terminated. I guess it takes a long time if you want to join to large tables directly in mysql? I am combining two tables each of size 30 million.

Comment: no, it is perfectly possible, if you have the proper indexes...

Comment: When I limit it to like 100 records it works perfectly

Comment: I can't even drop the table. I cancelled the query and I want to drop tableC. But it takes forever to drop it.

Comment: do you have indexes on the ID of A and B?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but you might be better off altering the table first and adding the column, then doing an update to populate that column

```
ALTER TABLE tableB ADD COLUMN colA yourColumnDefinition;
UPDATE tableB SET colA = <however you do it>;
```

I'm not totally sure which table you are adding the column to or how you are computing it. Based on the query you posted it looks like you are creating a mapping table to map two table's IDs to each other. If that is the case you would probably be better off putting a foreign key in one of the tables.

Again, this might not be exactly what you are looking for but if you just want to add a column to a table you already created this might be a better approach.